# Node.js response truncated

Tags: node.js

I am getting truncated response in my node service.

I am using http request.Please notify me any error in this code.

I want to get response without losing data.

My Code :

```
var config = require('./configuration')
exports.postDataDetails = function postDataDetails(http,url,port,path,inputParam,callback){  
var postData = inputParam;

var options = {
 hostname: url+":",
 port: port,
 path: path,
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(config.headerUsername + ':' + config.headerPassword).toString('base64'),
'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData,'utf8')//postData.length
 }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
res.setEncoding('utf8');

res.on('data', function (chunk) {
  console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  return callback(chunk);
});


res.on('end', function() {
  console.log('No more data in response.');
  return callback(JSON.stringify({status : "No more data in response."}));
  })
  });

 req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  return callback(JSON.stringify({status : "error"}));
 });

 // write data to request body
 req.write(postData);
  req.end();
 }
```

How to fix that problem.
Thanks.